# Parse Args that aren't declared

Tags: python

I'm writing a utility for running bash commands that essentially takes as input a string and a list optional argument and uses the optional arguments to interpolate string.

I'd like it to work like this:

```
interpolate.py Hello {user_arg} my name is {computer_arg} %% --user_arg=john --computer_arg=hal
```

The `%%` is a separator, it separates the string to be interpolated from the arguments. What follows is the arguments used to interpolate the string. In this case the user has chosen  `user_arg` and `computer_arg` as arguments. The program can't know in advance which argument names the user will choose.

My problem is how to parse the arguments? I can trivially split the input arguments on the separator but I can't figure out how to get optparse to just give the list of optional args as a dictionary, without specifying them in advance. Does anyone know how to do this without writing a lot of regex?

Comment: `optparse` is deprecated in favour of [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse).

Comment: Sure, I can use `argparse` if necessary. Can you do it in `argparse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this, you really don't need optparse or argparse - the benefit of such libraries are of little use in this circumstance (things like lone `-v` type arguments, checking for invalid options, value validation and so on)

```
def partition_list(lst, sep):
    """Slices a list in two, cutting on index matching "sep"

    >>> partition_list(['a', 'b', 'c'], sep='b')
    (['a'], ['c'])
    """
    if sep in lst:
        idx = lst.index(sep)
        return (lst[:idx], lst[idx+1:])
    else:
        return (lst[:], )

def args_to_dict(args):
    """Crudely parses "--blah=123" type arguments into dict like
    {'blah': '123'}
    """
    ret = {}
    for a in args:
        key, _, value = a.partition("=")
        key = key.replace("--", "", 1)
        ret[key] = value

    return ret


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    # Get stuff before/after the "%%" separator
    string, args = partition_list(sys.argv[1:], "%%")

    # Join input string
    string_joined = " ".join(string)

    # Parse --args=stuff
    d = args_to_dict(args)

    # Do string-interpolation
    print string_joined.format(**d)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you use '--' to separate options from arguments instead of %%, optparse/argparse will just give you the arguments as a plain list (treating them as positional arguments instead of switched). After that it's not 'a lot of' regex, it's just a mere split:

```
for argument in args:
    if not argument.startswith("--"):
        # decide what to do in this case...
        continue
    arg_name, arg_value = argument.split("=", 1)
    arg_name = arg_name[2:]
    # use the argument any way you like
```

Comment: Yes this works, thank though agree with below that you don't even need optparse/argparse.

Comment: argparse/optparse are needed if you also want to handle switches in addition to the arguments you interpolate, but if you don't need it than you can indeed drop it.

Answer (score 2):

With [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) you could use the [`parse_known_args`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args) method to consume predefined arguments and any additional arguments. For example, using the following script

```
import sys
import argparse

def main(argv=None):

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('string', type=str, nargs='*',
        help="""String to process. Optionally with interpolation
                (explain this here...)""")

    args, opt_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    print args
    print opt_args

    return 0

if __name__=='__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

and calling with

```
python script.py Hello, my name is {name} --name=chris
```

yields the following output:

```
Namespace(string=['Hello,' 'my', 'name', 'is', '{name}'])
['--name=chris']
```

All that is left to do is to loop through the `args` namespace looking for strings of the form `{...}` and replacing them with the corresponding element in `opt_args`, if present. (I'm not sure if argparse can do argument interpolation automatically, the above example is the only immediate solution which comes to mind).

Comment: Doesn't seem like argparse really gets me anything here. The main problem was dealing with the unknown arguments, I think the solutions below work well for that.