# Parsing arguments with ‘arg’ from a file

Tags: bash, max, command-line-arguments, user-input

I'm starting with bash code and I'm a bit lost with one script. First of all I would like to say that I have read this post  [Parse Args that aren't declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9883576/parse-args-that-arent-declared) but It hasn't helped me.

I have a file (affy.txt) with 9 columns and 6 rows. In the first column there are the gene's names and in the others numeric values from an experiment. My objective is to calculate the max, min and mean from the results from only one of all genes (ej: gene2 named ABC). Further, I would like to estimating the max, min and mean from only a column too.

I have created some code...

```
#!/bin/bash
echo This script runs the follow options over affy.txt

echo OPTIONS:
echo   -a   Find a gene and its tests\' result
echo   -b   Analyze one column\'s result

echo Write an option, and beside it, the name of the gene or the number of the column you are looking \for:
read OPTION

for arg; do 
    case "$1" in $OPTION
    -a) shift
        grep -n $1 affy.txt;;
        gene="$1";;
    -b) shift
        [0-9]*) col+="${1#-}"",";;
        #I'm not sure if -b) sintaxys it's ok  
    esac
    shift 
done
echo col="$col" gene="$gene"
```

Now I'm only focusing with It. I have created a code for my next step, estimation of the max, min and mean of the gene or column. But I don't care it now, I write it here to help you to understand the idea of the script.

```
#if [ "$col" = "" ]; 

    #then echo "Insert Columns please!"



#else

    #for i in $col; do  

    #echo

    #echo minim columna "$i"= `grep "$gene" affy.txt | cut -d ' ' -f"$i" | sort -n | head -1`
    #echo maxim columna "$i"= `grep "$gene" affy.txt | cut -d ' ' -f"$i" | sort -n | tail -1`
    #echo average columna "$i"= `grep "$gene" affy.txt | cut -d ' ' -f"$i" | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum/NR}'`

    #shift
    #done
#fi
```

Comment: what is your actual question?

Comment: you need a single argument which value is `a` or `b` ?

Comment: I already have solved this problem by myself. Now I'm in the next step, but also have a doubt, look at this my new post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608566/read-an-input-number-and-redirect-it-to-a-column-in-a-file